dpkg error on .deb package Ubuntu 22.04 Dell laptop
I am not able to install Accops hysecure software on my new Dell laptop which is running Ubuntu 22.04. After downloading the .deb file from a trusted site, and trying to install it using:
$ sudo dpkg -i HySecure_Client_5.1.4.16.deb
(Reading database... 165794 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack HySecure_Client_5.1.4.16.deb
Unpacking accopshysecure (5.1.4.16) ...
dpkg: error processing archive HySecure_Client_5.1.4.16.deb (--install):
trying to overwrite '/debian-binary', which is also in package dell-super-key 0.05 Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1)
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3)
Errors were encountered while processing:
HySecure_Client_5.1.4.16.deb


The text is hard to readPlease [edit] your question and copy&paste the commands together with the corresponding output and format it as code blocks. You can select the text and use the {} tool of the editor field or insert 3 tilde ~~~ or backtick characters as separate lines before and after the code block.

This question is similar to: dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in...". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
